# How to calibrate Polder instant read thermometer?

Tags: equipment

I have a Polder instant read thermometer that is uncalibrated since changing the battery. I have tried and failed to calibrate it and I don't have the owner's manual. Does anybody know the proper procedure? This is a model with a digital readout of the temperature on the face, and 4 buttons: on/off, hold, max, and calibrate. I've tried putting the stem in boiling water and pressing the calibrate button. I've also tried holding it down for 10 seconds. I've also tried the same thing, but with a glass of ice water. Help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can download [the manual for your particular model](http://www.polder.com/productinfo.html) on the polder website.

The instructions for [the model 574](http://polder.com.p2.hostingprod.com/images/instructions/574_instructions.pdf) (not sure if that's yours) are:

> Calibration function: Put the probe into iced water (32 F); wait until the reading value stabilizes. ␣ If the value reads between 23 to 41 F (-5  to 5 C), press the “CAL” key for 2 seconds. “CAL” will appear on the display for 2 seconds: the unit will then be calibrated automatically and return to its normal state and display 32 F.

You can always [give them a call](http://www.polder.com/contactus.html) too.